# Pronunciation of "negotiate"?

Tags: pronunciation

I was listening to a debate on the radio. There was a guest who was not a native English speaker.

He was pronouncing the verb "negotiate" as "/nego'si'eit/".

I supposed that  he made a mistake but, when he used this pronunciation multiple times, I decided to search and came across with [this](http://forum.wordreference.com/threads/difference-between-negociate-and-negotiate.1199034/) thread on WR.

However, there are many contradictory answers.

That motivated me to ask a similar question here.

Comment: Some native speakers palatalize the sibilant, some don't.

Answer (score 2):

As @TRomano commented, the "ti" syllable of *negotiate* is sometimes pronounced as *see* instead of *she*. This may be influenced by the [pronunciation of Latin words](http://www.preces-latinae.org/thesaurus/Introductio/Pronunciatio.html) containing "ti" before a vowel, but regardless of motivation, this pronunciation is quite common among native English speakers, particularly with the noun form, *negotiation*.

Surprisingly, the pronunciation guide in the [MW entry for *negotiate*](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/negotiate) displays the `÷` symbol before the -se- variant, which means that it is a pronunciation that ["many regard as unacceptable"](http://assets.merriam-webster.com/mw/static/pdf/help/guide-to-pronunciation.pdf) (the last entry on the last page of the linked PDF file explains their use of the symbol).

As a point of reference, [oxforddictionaries.com](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/negotiate) lists only the -she- pronunciation for *negotiate*.

Comment: thanks for the answer, but Oxford says it is pronounced -she- rather -se-

Comment: @Cardinal Sorry, that was a typo. Corrected now.

Answer (score 0):

Nego-she-ate
Is the correct pronunciation. You would probably spell it "negociate" instead of "negotiate" if you had never seen it written before.